# Ada - How Can I Get the 'First' and 'Last' Attributes of a Two-Dimensional Array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, ada

Let's say I have declared a type for a two-dimensional array and a variable of that type:

```
type Array2D is array(Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of Integer;
array : Array2D(1 .. 7, 1 .. 8);
```

The value of `array'First` is now 1, and the value of `array'Last` is now 7. How would I go about accessing the 'First' and 'Last' attributes of the second dimension of the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may access it with explicit dimension mark array'First(n)
See more here https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Attributes/%27First